# Grails spring-security-ldap plugin change user password for AD

Tags: grails, active-directory, spring-security-ldap

I have a grails application (2.5.0)  using Spring security and authenticating with the spring-security-ldap plugin (2.0-RC2) against a windows AD domain.

This works very well  to authenticate but now I have the requirement to allow the user to change their password (in fact to require it!).

Despite searching through the documentation,  Reading the code and searching with google All I can find is references to LdapUserDetailsManager.changePassword  but I cannot find a single example of how to use this.

I find in the plugin

```
public class GrailsLdapUserDetailsManager extends LdapUserDetailsManager 
    implements GrailsUserDetailsService {....
```

but this does not have the changePassword and I do not understand how to call it if it did.

I have looked through all the StackOverflow questions such as

[how to change password using spring ldap and spring security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24897149/how-to-change-password-using-spring-ldap-and-spring-security)

but the answers appear to be written in some other language and talk about things I do not have like xml files.

Can someone tell me,  preferably with an understandable example how I can implement a change Password feature in Grails against an ldap AD source in conjunction with the grails spring-security-ldap plugin?  Authentication without the ability to manage changing the passwords is just wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the ldapUserDetailsManager by injecting into your controller e.g.

gsp:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="layout" content="main">
        <title><g:message code="menu.item.change.password" /></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="maincontentdiv" role="main">

        <div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible" role="alert">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          flash.changePasswordMessage
        </div>

            <h3><g:message code="menu.item.change.password" /></h3>

            <g:form class="form-horizontal">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="currentPassword">Current password</label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <g:field type="password" name="currentPassword" class="form-control" required="true" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="newPassword">New password</label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <g:field type="password" name="newPassword" class="form-control" pattern=".{6,15}" required title="Password must be a minimum of 6 and a maximum of to 10 characters" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="confirmNewPassword">Confirm new password</label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <g:field type="password" name="confirmNewPassword" class="form-control" pattern=".{6,15}" required title="Password must be a minimum of 6 and a maximum of to 10 characters" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <g:render template="/templates/generic_submit_button" model="[btnname: 'changePassword', btntxt: 'Change password']" />

            </g:form>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Controller:

```
class ChangePasswordController {

    def ldapUserDetailsManager

    def index() {
        if ( params.changePassword ) {
            try {
                if ( params.newPassword.equals( params.confirmNewPassword ) ) {
                    ldapUserDetailsManager.changePassword( params.currentPassword, params.newPassword )
                }
                else { 
                    throw new InvalidParameterException( 'Please ensure the new password and confirm new password fields match' )
                }
            }
            catch( all ) {
                flash.changePasswordMessage= all.message
            }
        }
    }
}
```